# php upload script issue

Tags: php, html

The following form is on my page html page

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is the script for the php

```
<?php

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000000))
      {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "pics/2012/Blackhall Primary/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
    ?>
```

When I press select on the form, nothing. It was working fine. The page with the form is called upload pictuture.html and the scriptt is called upload_file.php they are both on the root and the folder pics/2012/blackhall primary does exist and the pics dir is on the root also.

This was working but is not, can anyone see any errors I've made.

Thanks
Ross

Comment: Does it echo file info? Did you try to remove space in folder name? Did you check error_log ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your privileges and by whom script is executed (usually *www-data* or *apache2*) - this account must has write and probably read access to directory, where pictures are uploaded.

Anyway, checking file type based on `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` isn't safe. This can be easily falsified by hacker.